# CSS Stretch Container to Width of Widest Hidden Child Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers

I have very simple example of an un-ordered list with a black border, and one of its child elements hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/Sm9Lx/1/. Notice how the hidden child element is considerably wider than the visible element, but the container only scales to the width of the visible child.

Is there a way within CSS to automatically scale the width of this container to the width of its widest child element, even if that element is hidden?

I know that this is possible with JavaScript, but I would like to avoid a scripting hack and go straight CSS, if possible.

Also, I'd like to avoid setting a specific width because in my actual application, my container will contain visual objects of unknown widths.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `visibility: hidden;` rather than `display: none;` on the hidden `li`

- `visibility: hidden;` retains the elements space
- `display: none;` acts as if the element doesnt exist in the markup

Comment: With only visibility: hidden, the ul expands to fit the height of the element as well. Not sure if that what OP wants. In my answer below, I added height: 0

Comment: Ah! Didn't even think about visibility! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
<li style="visibility: hidden; height: 0;">This is not the first list element, ok?</li>
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: none` you can use `opacity: 0`